# Not getting WeChat Follow response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, wechat

I have a Debugging Official Account with WeChat. I have entered my public URL and Token into the field provided http://admin.wechat.com/debug/sandbox and also attempted debugging the request with http://admin.wechat.com/debug/

My ASP.Net [.Net4.5] Web API application's POST Method looks like the following :

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostMessage([FromBody]Strikemedia.Api.WeChat.TextMessage value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            var richMediaMessage = new RichMediaMessage();
            richMediaMessage.touser = value.FromuserName;

            //Create Article
            var item = new Article()
            {
                title = "Didn't receive anything back",
                description = "Mind entering 'test'",
                picurl = "URL",
                url = "URL"
            };
            var articles = new List<Article>();
            articles.Add(item);
            richMediaMessage.articles = articles;
            richMediaMessage.articleCount = articles.Count;
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, richMediaMessage, "application/json");
        }

        var exploded = value.Content.Split(' ')[0];

        var richMedia = new RichMediaMessage();
        richMedia.touser = value.FromuserName;

        //Create Article
        var article = new Article() { 
            title = response.KeywordDescription,
            description = response.Response,
            picurl = "URL",
            url = "URL"
        };
        var _articles = new List<Article>();
        _articles.Add(article);
        richMedia.articles = _articles;
        richMedia.articleCount = _articles.Count;

        //Return response
        var resp = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, richMedia, "application/json");
        //resp.RequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        return resp;
    }
```

It needs to respond with a RichMessageType in JSON format and is received in XML format

Am i missing something or have i overlooked something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that you have submitted the URL and token into admin.wechat.com and that the URL and token was accepted?

Also note you get XML and you respond with XML no json response.

Have you had a look at: http://youtu.be/kB20Zf51QWU
And then this
http://youtu.be/_2FSzD2B2F0

This is the documentation for the XML can be found when you google "wechat guide to message api"

So if you still not receiving a success message when submitting your app on admin.wechat.com then you can send me your test URL here. To find this URL check your access logs to see exactly what URL wechat is calling. Then post it here. Please note that when you hit the URL as wechat will you should only see the "echostr" printed on the screen (when viewing the source in your browser). No XML no HTML just the echostr.

Also make sure there are no spaces or newlines after or before the "echostr". When you view the source it should only be one line which is the echostr GET param's value.

The XML response only comes in later when you actually start responding to messages from users. For now Wechat is just confirming if your security is setup correctly.

Also note if your server is load balanced you will have to skip the signature validation and build your own validation when a echostr GET parameter gets passed through and only echo the "echostr" param to screen.

Comment: We managed to figure out that the url and token required to proceed, however after many attempts to submit the required echostr, the panel still issues a "configuration failed" error

Comment: The Request URL we are supplied by weChat is a follows : http://api.strikemedia.co.za/WeChat/WeChatTest/api/request?signature=e6448061ece1c0f30e6364b8584f0c76a2db1150&echostr=6496574268439509975&timestamp=1397132240&nonce=119870065
Which returns a text/plain response from our side

Comment: Please confirm if api.strikemedia.co.za is a load balanced solution? If it is you have to remove the signature validation.

Comment: I can confirm, we do not have a load balancing solution.

Comment: There is a space/newline at the end of your echostr . Please remove that.

Comment: @DeveloperX quick question, for the messages that gets posted to the url provided, what headers are present in the request?

Comment: @Armand Please post a new question on stackoverflow as I think that is a very valid question. Then please send me the link. Will answer in detail there. We are trying to build up as much answers here as possible in order to facilitate everyone getting integrated.

Comment: @DeveloperX The removal of the newline carrier fixed the problem. The application is now registered, thanx

Comment: @Armand: HEADERS

Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 682
Content-Type: text/xml
Date: Fri, 11 Apr 2014 09:47:38 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Aspnet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET